# How to fix error 1119 as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to as3. And i'm struggling with the error 1119. I don't understand how to fix it. 
the error is:

Access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type flash.text:TextField.

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

// public function kan je ook gebruiken in een ander as. file
// private function kan je alleen gebruiken in hetzelfde as. file 
public class firstGame extends MovieClip
{

    public var mcPlayer:MovieClip;

    private var leftKeyIsDown:Boolean;
    private var rightKeyIsDown: Boolean;

    private var aMissileArray: Array;
    private var aEnemyArray: Array; 

    public var scoreTxt: TextField;
    public var ammoTxt : TextField;

    public var menuEnd: mcEndGameScreen;

    private var tEnemyTimer : Timer;

    private var nScore : Number;
    private var nAmmo : Number;

    public function firstGame ()
    {
        playGameAgain(null);
    }

    private function playGameAgain (e:Event) : void
    {
        //initilaiz variables
        aMissileArray = new Array ();
        aEnemyArray = new Array ();

        nScore = 0;
        nAmmo = 20;

        mcPlayer.visible = true;

        updateScoreText();
        updateAmmoText();

        menuEnd.addEventListener("PLAY_AGAIN", playGameAgain);
        menuEnd.hideScreen ();

        //trace("First Game Loaded");
        //Listern for key presses and relesead

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
        //Setup game event loop
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);

        // create a timer object
        tEnemyTimer = new Timer (1000);
        // listener for timer intervals
        tEnemyTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addEnemy); 
        // start out timer
        tEnemyTimer.start();
    }

    private function updateScoreText (): void
    {
        scoreTxt.txt = "Score: " + nScore;
    }

    private function updateAmmoText (): void
    {
        ammoTxt.txt =  "Ammo: " + nAmmo; 
    }
    private function addEnemy (e:TimerEvent) : void
    {
        //trace ("timer ticks")
        // create a new enemy object
        var newEnemy:mcEnemy = new mcEnemy ();
        // add object to the stage
        stage.addChild (newEnemy);
        // add enemy to new enemy to a new enemy array
        aEnemyArray.push(newEnemy);
        trace (aEnemyArray.length);

    }

    private function gameLoop (e:Event) : void
    {
        playerControl();
        clampPlayerToStage();
        checkMissileOffscreen();
        checkEnemiesOffscreen();
        checkMissilesHitsEnemy();
        checkEndGameCondition();
    }

    private function chechEndGameCondition (): void
    {
        //check if player has 0 missiles left and 0 on screen
        if ( nAmmo == 0 && aMissileArray.length == 0)
        {
            // stop player movement
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyUp);
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyDown);
            // hide the player
            mcPlayer.visible = false;
            // stop spawing enemies
            tEnemyTimer.stop();
            // clear enemies on screen
            for each ( var enemy: mcEnemy in aEnemyArray)
            {
                // destroy the enemy
                enemy.destroyEnemy();
                // remove from enemy array
                aEnemyArray.splice( 0,1);
            }
            // stop the game loop
            if(aEnemyArray.length == 0 )
            {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
            }
            // show our endgame screen
            menuEnd.showScreen(); 
        }

    }

    private function checkMissilesHitsEnemy (): void
    {
        // loop trough current missiles
        for (var i : int = 0 ; i < aMissileArray.length; i++)
        {
            // get our current missile in the  i loop
            var currentMissile : mcMissile = aMissileArray [i];

            // loop trough all our enemies
            // gebruik geen i want die is al gebruikt dus j
            for (var j: int = 0 ; j < aEnemyArray.length; j++)
            {
                // get the current enemy in the j loop
                var currentEnemy: mcEnemy = aEnemyArray [j];

                // test if our current enemy is hitting our current missile
                if(currentMissile.hitTestObject(currentEnemy))
                {
                    // create an explosion
                    // create a new explosion instance/movielcip
                    var newExplosion: mcExplosion = new mcExplosion ();
                    // add our explosion to the stage
                    stage.addChild( newExplosion)
                    // position our expolosion to our enemy
                    newExplosion.x = currentEnemy.x; 
                    newExplosion.y = currentEnemy.y;

                    // remove the missile
                    currentMissile.destroyMissile();
                    // remove the missile from missile array
                    aMissileArray.splice(i, 1);
                    // remove the enemy from the stage
                    currentEnemy.destroyEnemy();
                    // remove the enemy from the enemy array
                    aEnemyArray.splice(j, 1);

                    // add one to our score
                    nScore++;
                    updateScoreTxt ();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private function checkEnemiesOffscreen (): void
    {
        // loop trough all our enemies
        for (var i:int = 0;i < aEnemyArray.length; i++)
        {
            // get our current ememy in the loop
            var currentEnemy: mcEnemy = aEnemyArray [i];
            // when enemy moves left and is has gone past the and of the left from the stage
            if (currentEnemy.sDirection == "L" && currentEnemy.x  - (currentEnemy.width/2))
            {
                // Remove enemy from our array
                aEnemyArray.slice(i,1); 
                // Remove enemy from stage
                currentEnemy.destroyEnemy();
            } else
            if (currentEnemy.sDirection == "R" && currentEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth + (currentEnemy.width/2))
            {
                // Remove enemy from our array
                aEnemyArray.slice(i,1); 
                // Remove enemy from stage
                currentEnemy.destroyEnemy();
            }

        }
    }

    private function checkMissileOffscreen():void
    {
        //Loop throw all our missiles in our missle array
            // i = counter object
        for (var i: int = 0; i < aMissileArray.length; i++)
        {
            //Get the current missile in the loop
            var currentMissile : mcMissile = aMissileArray [i];
            //Test if current missile is out the buttom of the screen
            if (currentMissile.y > 450 )
            {
                    //Remove current missile from the array
                    aMissileArray.splice(i,1);
                    //Destroy our missile
                    currentMissile.destroyMissile();
            }

        }
    }

    private function clampPlayerToStage ():void
    {
        // if our player is to the left of the stage
        if (mcPlayer.x < (mcPlayer.width/2))
        {
            // set our player to left of the stage
            mcPlayer.x = mcPlayer.width/2;
        }
        // if our player is to the right of the stage
        else if (mcPlayer.x > (stage.stageWidth - (mcPlayer.width/2)))
        {
            //set our player to right of the stage
            mcPlayer.x = stage.stageWidth - (mcPlayer.width/2);
        }
    }

    private function playerControl ():void
    {
            // if our left key is down currently
        if (leftKeyIsDown == true)
        {
                //move to left
            mcPlayer.x -= 5;
        }

            // if our right key is currently down
        if (rightKeyIsDown)
        {
                //move to right
            mcPlayer.x += 5;
        }   
    }

    private function keyUp (e:KeyboardEvent): void
    {
        //trace(e.keyCode)
        //if your left is released
        if (e.keyCode == 37)
        {
            //left key is released
            leftKeyIsDown = false;
        }
        //if your right is released 
        if (e.keyCode == 39)
        {
            //right key is released
            rightKeyIsDown = false;
        }
        //if our spacebarr is released
        if (e.keyCode == 32)
        {
            // test if player has missiles left
            if (nAmmo > 0) 
            {
            nAmmo--;
            updateAmmoTxt();
            //fire a missile
            fireMissile ();
            }
        }

    }

    private function fireMissile ():void 
    {
        // create a new missisile object
        var newMissile : mcMissile = new mcMissile ();
        // add to stage
        stage.addChild(newMissile);
        // position missile
        newMissile.x = mcPlayer.x;
        newMissile.y = mcPlayer.y;
        //add our new missile to our missile array
        aMissileArray.push (newMissile);
        trace(aMissileArray.length)
    }

    private function keyDown (e:KeyboardEvent): void
    {

        //trace(e.keyCode)
        //if your left is pressed
        if (e.keyCode == 37)
        {
            //left key is pressed
            leftKeyIsDown = true;
        }
        //if your right is pressed
        if (e.keyCode == 39)
        {
            //right key is pressed
            rightKeyIsDown = true;
        }
    }


    }

}
```

if someone can help me with the scoreTxt i think i can do the ammoTxt by myself.

Comment: Lemme know if my answer helps. Your code looks like you're trying your best to learn how to program and how to make games, even despite things like language barriers, and I respect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a typo `scoreTxt.txt` should be `scoreTxt.text`.

---

Error 1119 says `Access of possibly undefined property <propertyname> through a reference with static type <typename>.`

This means that some bit of your code uses a possibly uninitialized object. In your case, it's `scoreTxt`, as you've figured out.

To see WHY it crashes, you need to manually go through your program. I prefer to uncomment whole blocks of code and slowly narrow the problem down, but that's not needed here.

First, you hit `firstGame()`, the constructor of your document class.

This in turn hits `playGameAgain()`, with a `null` argument.

That function runs through some code... and then it hits `updateScoreText()`. And there it crashes. That gives the following call stack and executed code:

Call stack:

```
updateScoreText()
from playGameAgain(null) on line "updateScoreText();"
from firstGame() on line "playGameAgain(null);"
```

Executed code:

```
playGameAgain(null);

//leads to...
//initilaiz variables
aMissileArray = new Array ();
aEnemyArray = new Array ();

nScore = 0;
nAmmo = 20;

mcPlayer.visible = true;

updateScoreText();
//leads to...
scoreTxt.txt = "Score: " + nScore;//crash
```

You need to link or create `scoreTxt` first. It's possibly `null` or `undefined` now, which is what's causing the 1119 error. To link the `scoreTxt` so your document class can find it, you should give them instance names. If I were you, I'd verify my instance names.

You'll also have to do this for `ammoTxt`.

Comment: the textfield is already on the stage and is called scoreTxt and he is dynamic.  And if i put var scoreTxt: TextField = new TextField(); before upDateScoreText (); it doesn't work.

Comment: @FaceMann I've updated my answer to be a bit better in explanation. Does the `scoreTxt` on the stage have an instance name set?

Comment: scoreTxt is the instancename

Comment: @FaceMann are they (`scoreTxt` and `ammoTxt` textfields) on the first frame of your timeline?

Comment: @FaceMann If you comment out the lines `scoreTxt.txt = "Score: " + nScore;` and `ammoTxt.txt =  "Ammo: " + nAmmo;` and replace them with `trace(scoreTxt)` and `trace(ammoTxt)` instead, what do you get?

Comment: [object textfield] [object textfield]

Comment: @FaceMann I have no idea why it would give you an error then. Add a trace(scoreTxt.text) after it.

Comment: Say... You made the textfields dynamic... What do you have set as variable for them?

Comment: @FaceMann and just to humor me, what happens if you put the original line where you set scoreTxt to something back, below the traces? Because it should just work...

Comment: i think it worked. And i replaced scoreTxt.txt by scoreTxt.text Thanks!!